# Combinatorics problem, room configurations

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

Say I have a bunch of hotel rooms, suitable for 1,2 or 3 persons.

A group of 4 persons would like to book and I want to present them with all the possible configurations, since different configurations have different prices.

Possible combinations include:

- 4 * 1 person room
- 2 * 2 person room
- 1 * 3 person room + 1 * 1 person room
- etcetera, etcetera

How would I go about calculating the different groupings?

An added complexity is that some of these persons may be children, which should always be combined with adults in a room. I figured I should just calculate all combinations and filter out the ones who don't satisfy this constraint.

Any hints, tips or pointers?

Comment: This is kind of P(n), but not entirely. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html (It does only return the number of posibilties per se. but maybe you can find something in this article)

Comment: thanks, but i dont htink this is it, since roomsize can vary, could be just 2 & 4 person rooms for example

Comment: Mh brute force probably then. Recursion plus branching everytime you add one person to one room. + avoiding/deleting duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The way the problem is phrased suggests that the number of room types is small, and so is the largest required group size.

With this in mind, I'd use depth-first search with memoization. In Python:

```
@memoized
def search(n, room_types):
  ret = set()
  for t in room_types:
    if t >= n:
      ret.add((t,))
    else:
      for cfg in search(n - t, room_types):
        if sum(cfg) >= n:
          ret.add(cfg)
        else:
          ret.add(tuple(sorted(list(cfg) + [t])))
  return ret

print sorted(search(4, (1, 2, 3)))
```

This produces:

```
[(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

`@memoized` comes from [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#CA-14a3b2d211730af8f363ef76b2923a715df322e7_1).

Comment: thanks, I think it's a step in the right direction, but I suspect the child/adult constraint is pretty hard to apply to the output of this, since it desribes actual combinations of persons, not just the amount of persons.